# Synchronizing AKPlayer with AKSampleMetronome

Tags: audiokit

I am trying to use AKSamplerMetronome as a master clock in my (sort of) multi audiofile playback project. I wanted AKPlayers to be started in sync with Metronome's downbeat. Mixing AKPlayer and AKSamplerMetronome as AudioKit.output was successful, however, I am struggling to connect AKPlayer.start with AKSamplerMetronome.beatTime(or something else I haven't figured out) so the playback starts with the Metronome's downbeat in sync (and repeat every time Metronome hits downbeat). Here's what I've written:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let metronome = AKSamplerMetronome()
let player = AKPlayer(audioFile: try! AKAudioFile(readFileName: "loop.wav"))
let mixer = AKMixer()

func startAudioEngine() {
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        print(error)
        fatalError()
    }
}

func makeConnections() {
    player >>> mixer
    metronome >>> mixer
    AudioKit.output = mixer
}

func startMetronome() {

    metronome.tempo = 120.0
    metronome.beatVolume = 1.0
    metronome.play()
}

func preparePlayer() {

    player.isLooping = true
    player.buffering = .always
    player.prepare()
// I wanted AKPlayer to be repeated based on Metronome's downbeat.

}

func startPlayer() {

    let startTime = AVAudioTime.now() + 0.25
    player.start(at: startTime)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    makeConnections()
    startAudioEngine()
    preparePlayer()
    startPlayer()
    startMetronome()

}

}
```

My problem is that, AKPlayer's start point(at:) doesn't recognize AKSamplerMetronome's properties, maybe because it's not compatible with AVAudioTime? I tried something like:

```
let startTime = metronome.beatTime + 0.25
player.start(at: startTime)
```

But this doesn't seem to be an answer (as "cannot convert value type 'Double' to expected argument type 'AVAudioTime?'). It would be extremely helpful if someone could help me exploring Swift/AudioKit. <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are calling the AVAudioTime playback function with a Double parameter. That's incorrect. If you want to start the AKPlayer with a seconds param, use player.play(when: time)

In general, you're close. This is how you do it:

```
    let startTime: Double = 1

    let hostTime = mach_absolute_time()
    let now = AVAudioTime(hostTime: hostTime)
    let avTime = now.offset(seconds: startTime)
    metronome.setBeatTime(0, at: avTime)
    player.play(at: avTime)
```

Basically you need to give a common clock to each unit (mach_absolute_time()), then use AVAudioTime to start them at the exact time. The metronome.setBeatTime is telling the metronome to reset it's 0 point at the passed in avTime.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. If I may ask one more, is there a way I can repeat the loop.wav audiofile based on the metronome's downbeat, not based on the audiofile's own length? Since there are 4 ticks on a bar, I want AKPlayer to be repeated on every first tick. I am trying several different things but cannot figure out what to do with "player.isLooping = true" part... or something else. much appreciated.

Comment: set the player.endTime = to the duration of a bar. then player.buffering = .always, player.isLooping = true. Note you can just call: player.preroll(from: 0, to: durationOfBar). That will set the endTime as well as replace your player.prepare() call.

Comment: 4 beats at 120bpm = 2 seconds

Comment: Hi @RyanFrancesconi, I apologize for raising this question so late, but what if the player needs to be stopped, the metronome should play further, then replace the file with the player and start the player so that it plays in time with the metronome. Is it possible?

Comment: Actually I think it may work better to use AKClipPlayer. I think part of the issue is that AKPlayer is predominantly hostTime based whereas the same metronome uses AKTimeline which is sampleTime based. I made AKPlayer to be sync'd to video which seemed easier to do via hostTime. Recently I made AKPlayer compatible with offline rendering which required a switch to sampleTime internally - but I haven't attempted to sync to the metronome since then. It's definitely possible to do, I just haven't lately.

Comment: Those comments are in regard to AVAudioTime scheduling.

Comment: Yes, I tried to calculate the time for this, but another problem arose in the process: I took two samples with the sound of a metronome, one tempo, but a different number of beats. One sample = 1 beat, another sample = 2 beat, and when I run it like this:
player1.looping = true
player2.looping = true
player1.buffering = .always
player2.buffering = .always

let startTime = AVAudioTime.now() + 0.25
player1.play(at: startTime)
player2.play(at: startTime)
And it does not play synchronously; 

So it should be? If you run two samples of the same length, it plays synchronously.

Comment: And the question is: does AKClipPlayer support looping mode?

Comment: the clip player is pretty limited compared to AKPlayer in functionality - that said it was intended as more of a "track" where you have various clips that are internally scheduled. Sorry I don't have a better answer about this at this time.